# Populating forms and selecting defaults in Flask-WTF

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a form that is used for composing and editing blog posts like this:

```
class EditorForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=1, max=250)])
    body = PageDownField('Body', validators=[DataRequired()])
    tags = SelectMultipleField('Tags', coerce=int)
    timestamp = DateTimeField('Timestamp')
    published = BooleanField('Publish?')
    update = BooleanField('Update Timestamp?')
    delete = SubmitField('Delete')
    submit = SubmitField('Save')
```

In my view I distinguish between editing existing posts and creating new ones. For existing posts, if they have associated tags, I want these to be highlighted in the `SelectMultipleField` on the form so the user can see them.

If these are highlighted and I want to remove the tags, I need to be able to unhighlight them and submit the form to do so.

Here are the relevant parts of my view as it stands now:

```
@app.route('/editor/<slug>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/editor/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def editor(slug=None):
    # old post or new post?
    if slug:
        post = Post.query.filter_by(slug=slug).first()
    else:
        post = Post()

    # populate form, blank for new post
    form = EditorForm(obj=post)
    
    # populate tags field
    form.tags.choices = [(tag.id, tag.tag) for tag in Tag.query.order_by('tag')]

    # declare list for tag highlights on GET
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form.tags.default = []

    # if post has linked tags, highlight them
    if post.tags:
        for tag in post.tags:
            if tag.id not in form.tags.default:
                form.tags.default.append(tag.id)
        form.process()
```

In fishing around [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099741/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-wtforms-selectfield) related to my issue, I have discovered that I can't directly use `form.tags.data` to highlight associated tags because this means user action on the form is ignored for that field, even though the right choices will be highlighted. This is why I am using `form.tags.default`.

`form.tags.default` seems to work for highlighting the correct tags, BUT `form.process()` wipes all the other fields filled out by `form = EditorForm(obj=post)`.

So my question is: how can I populate my form with existing post data AND highlight the right tags in the same instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have obtained the result I wanted with this issue. Part of my original problem was actually related to some code in the view that I didn't post in my question.

On `if form.validate_on_submit():`, I was appending the tags in `form.tags.data` (highlighted choices) to my `post.tags`.
In cases where posts already had attached tags this meant that deselecting the defaults in the field was indeed emptying `form.tags.data` as desired, but `post.tags` still had the original data anyway, hence no change.

This was solved with the following:

```
# empty tags list then add highlighted choices
    post.tags = []
    for id in form.tags.data:
        t = Tag.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
        post.tags.append(t)
```

I also changed my code that populated the form to be simpler. I was wrong about needing to use `default` over `data` (and frankly I don't understand the difference between the two):

```
    # populate form, blank for new post
    form = EditorForm(obj=post)
    # populate tags field
    form.tags.choices = [(tag.id, tag.tag) for tag in Tag.query.order_by('tag')]
    # populate defaults only on GET otherwise user choice overidden
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # declare default (highlighted) tags list
        form.tags.data = []
        # if post has tags, highlight them
        if post.tags:
            for tag in post.tags:
                form.tags.data.append(tag.id)
```