# WTForms: how do I set a default value for an HTML5 Widget?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to use the WTForms color input field.

How can I set a default value (e.g. `#ff0000`) for the input field?

This is how I define the form:

```
from wtforms.widgets.html5 import ColorInput

class ColoursForm(Form):
   background_color = StringField(widget=ColorInput())
```

This is the view:

```
@app.route("/colours/<token>/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_colours(token):
   form = ColoursForm(request.form)
   if request.method == 'GET':
      return render_template('colours_edit.html', form=form, token=token)
   else:  # Request = post
      return redirect(url_for('view_scoreboard', token=token))
```

In my Jinja2 Template (colours_edit.html) I do this:

```
<p> {{ form.background_color() }} Pick a color here </p>
```

It all works, but I don't know how to set a default value. What **doesn't work** is this in the form:

```
background_color = StringField(widget=ColorInput(), default="#ff00ff")
```

Comment: `return render_template('colors.html', form=form)` actually does work for me. Perhaps there's a mistake in how you pasted the example?

Comment: I tried this on my own example and it didn't work. The question linked in my answer explores this more. Apparently this doesn't always work for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to check and then set the data value in your view. Notice the two new lines after you get the form:

```
@app.route("/colours/<token>/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_colours(token):
   form = ColoursForm(request.form)
   if not form.background_color.data:
       form.background_color.data = "#ff00ff"
   if request.method == 'GET':
       return render_template('colours_edit.html', form=form, token=token)
   else:  # Request = post
       return redirect(url_for('view_scoreboard', token=token))
```

No default:

[image]

Default `#ff00ff`:

[image]

Here is a minimal example for anyone else curious to try it out:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from wtforms.widgets.html5 import ColorInput
from wtforms import Form, StringField


class ColoursForm(Form):
    background_color = StringField(widget=ColorInput())


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def edit_colours():
    form = ColoursForm()
    if not form.background_color.data:
        form.background_color.data = "#ff00ff"
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("colors_edit.html", form=form)
```

`colors_edit.html` is the same as OPs (make sure to put it in a `templates` folder):

```
<p> {{ form.background_color() }} Pick a color here </p>
```

I don't know why your first attempt at setting a default doesn't work. Didn't work for me either. It seems like it should. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099741/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-wtforms-selectfield) answer dives in a little deeper.

Comment: It seems strange to me that there is no solution using the `default` keyword. But you earned your bounty anyway . Thanks!