# Set default selected option in template?

Tags: flask, select, jinja2, flask-wtforms, wtforms

Im trying to set te default option to a select with the following macro:

```
{% macro render_sfield(classParent, fieldGiven, classField="", icono="", id="", default="") -%}
  <div class="input-field {{classParent}}">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">{{icono}}</i>
    {{ fieldGiven(class="validate " + classField, id=id, selected=default) }}
    <label for="{{id}}">{{ fieldGiven.label.text }}</label>
  </div>
{%- endmacro %}
```

but doesn´t work. I also tried with `default=default` and `value=default` but nothing works.

What I get is, as ever, the first option that I have in the default Field : `turno = SelectField("Turno:",validators=[DataRequired()], choices=[('Matutino', 'Matutino'), ('Vespertino', 'Vespertino')])`. **Matutino** in this case.

In template i´m using it like this:

```
{% if datos %}
  {{ render_sfield("row", persona_form.turno, icono='schedule', id="turno-empleado", default=datos.turno) }}
{% else %}
  {{ render_sfield("row", persona_form.turno, icono='schedule', id="turno-empleado", default="") }}
{% endif %}
```

To re-use the template. Do you know how to do this??

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099741/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-wtforms-selectfield

Comment: Thanks, its not the same problem but that question helped me to solve mine, should I delete this? Or post my solution? SORRY, im new in this, anyways thank you